# Binding (culture) not working when tabitem not visible

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight:

I have a problem with the binding when used in a tabControl. I use the NO-NB culture which means that the decimal separator is , (comma) and not . (dot) as in US-EN. The binding works well as long as the tab is visible. If I choose another tab and then saves the data to the database (using EF), the text 1,25 is converted to 125.00 and stored as such in the database.

I have set the this.Language .... in the constructor to be certain that the right culture is set. And, as said, it works when the tab is visible.

Anyone else encountered this problem and have a solution to this?

Edit:
I realized that this behaviour also occurs when just switching the tabs. It seems like there is a bug in the framework that reset or do not take into account the currentCulture or CurrentUIculture.

Comment: Do you set the UI Culture with a binding? Shouldn't it be set once at the program start? And yes, the binding may not fire if the element is not visible.

Comment: I do not set the culture at the program start since the program reads the culture from the user in the database and sets it, but I set the culture in the constructor since there is a bug in Silverlight/WPF.

Comment: At the constuctor of the current ChildWindow where the problem is.

Comment: Well, but this seems to have nothing to do with binding, right? Could you perhaps post the code where the problem is?

Comment: I have figured it out, finding that the language setting of the textbox is not inherited from the tabItem, nor from the class (ChildWindow) and nor from the global settings.

Comment: By, the way. Thanks, @Vlad, for your interest and help in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and the solution. When a textbox resides on a tabItem in a ChildWindow, it will not inherit the language setting. I printed some debug-messages from the program and after setting:

```
this.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name); // nb-no
```

in the ChildWindow constructor and also setting the:

```
tabItem.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name); // nb-no
```

the TextBox was still en-us and not nb-no. Therefore setting:

```
textBox.Language = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

worked like a charm. I consider this a bug in the Silverlight framework.